# MVC VB.NET Build SelectListItem/ DropDownListFor dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

Here is my model:

```
Public Class subjectListModel 
    Public Property selectedActivity As String
    Public Property activities As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)
End Class
```

Here is my view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(x) x.selectedActivity, Model.activities, New With {.onchange = "this.form.submit();"})
```

And here is my controller:

```
Function populateList()

        'this is hardcoded at present, because I haven't been able to 
        'dynamically add to this IEnumerable. The implication is, I need a 
        'code change every time I add a new subject to my app ...


        Dim model = New subjectListModel With {
        .activities = {
                New SelectListItem() With {.Value = activityList(0), .Text = activityList(0)},
                New SelectListItem() With {.Value = activityList(1), .Text = activityList(1)},
                New SelectListItem() With {.Value = activityList(2), .Text = activityList(2)},
                New SelectListItem() With {.Value = activityList(3), .Text = activityList(3)},
                New SelectListItem() With {.Value = activityList(4), .Text = activityList(4)},
                New SelectListItem() With {.Value = activityList(5), .Text = activityList(5)},
                New SelectListItem() With {.Value = activityList(6), .Text = activityList(6)},
                New SelectListItem() With {.Value = activityList(7), .Text = activityList(7)},
                New SelectListItem() With {.Value = activityList(8), .Text = activityList(8)},
                New SelectListItem() With {.Value = activityList(9), .Text = activityList(9)}
            }
        }

        Return View(model)
    End Function
```

This works fine, and displays a drop down list containing the first ten of my options. I have many more that I wish to display. I have looked at building a list by dynamically adding items from my array of strings and then trying to convert it to IEnumerable. I have spent hours now looking at C# code that appears to do what I want, but despite numerous attempts I have been unable to get this working in VB. A big part of the problem is that I do not really understand this stuff. Any help would be appreciated !

This is one way I attempted to create a loop:

```
Dim dropDown = New List(Of SelectListItem)
For j = 0 To 100
        dropDown.Add(New SelectListItem With {.Text = activityList(j), .Value = activityList(j)})
Next j
```

I then came unstuck trying to convert this to IEnumerable.

This is another way I attempted to create a loop:

```
Dim model = New subjectListModel
For j = 0 To 100
    model.activities(New SelectListItem With {.Text = activityList(j), .Value = activityList(j)})
Next j
```

This errors with "Too many arguments"

Comment: Why not a use a loop to iterate the collection and add a new `SeelctListItem`? Or better still a linq `.Select(x => new SelectListItem { ... })`?

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my question to show one of the ways I attempted to create a loop. If you could just show me how to iterate the collection ...

Comment: Sorry, not clear what your asking. Your have already created a `List<SelectListItem>` which is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` - you dont need to _convert this to IEnumerable_ because it already is.

Comment: Thank you Stephen. I have updated my question. My problem is really that I do not know how to iterate IEnumerable<SelectListItem>.

Comment: If you wanting to add them to you model property, then change the proeprty to `activities As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)` and use `model.activities(New SelectListItem ....`

Comment: Sorry Stephen, but I don't follow. I have already defined activities As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem). Is there any chance you would sketch out your solution in an answer and then I can accept it ?

Comment: Oops, that should have read - If you wanting to add them to you model property, then change the property to activities As `IList(Of SelectListItem)` and use `model.activities(New SelectListItem ....`. Alternativly just use the code in your `Dim dropDown = New List(Of SelectListItem)` example and then `model.activities = dropDown`

Comment: That's great thanks Stephen - I used the latter approach and it worked fine. If you would open an answer, I will put in the details and accept the answer. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first loop (assigning to `Dim dropDown = New List(Of SelectListItem)`) creates `IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)` so you can just assign that to your `subjectListModel` using `model.activities = dropDown`.

Alternatively you can use a LINQ query

```
model.activities = activityList.Select(Function(x) New SelectListItem() 
    With { .Text = x, .Value = x })
```

and add `.Take(100)` if you only want the first 100 items.

Comment: Thanks Stephen - the first solution worked perfectly.